# Is it acceptable to also tag with the language example when doing a code-translation?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was tempted to retag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11303596/908879) to remove the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag, but I am unsure if I should.

When someone knows a way to do something in X language and wants to translate it to Y language, is it acceptable to tag with both languages (X and Y)?

I felt useless even though it was taged with my strong tag. I don't know if this should happen, it wasted my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question had *nothing* to do with Javascript, so it shouldn't be tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).  I've removed the tag.